# Overpass request to filter all building by population

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am looking for an Openstreetmap overpass request, where I can get all Solarmodules from cities whose population is above or under a certain threshold. Something like this in pseudocode:

get all solar modules from cities WHERE city.population<100000
out;